# Google Analytics Dashboard AJAX Function Does Not get values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have used the following function to pass certain data to an ASP.Net web service.

```
function setJsonSer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Email: 'clientlink@russell.com',
            Password: 'russell1234',
            URL: getVaria()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success alert    " + data);
            var sTitle = $(data).find('string').text();
            alert("sTitle Alert " + sTitle);
            alert("The data string    " + data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error in simple method');
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/GetMessage",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Email: 'clientlink@russell.com',
            Password: 'russell1234',
            URL: getVaria()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(success);
            var sTitle = $(data).find('string').text();
            alert(sTitle);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error in simple method');
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

I have alert the.

```
data: {
    Email: 'clientlink@russell.com',
    Password: 'russell1234',
    URL: getVaria()
},
```

However the alert is `[object document]`. I think that should the alert not be. So you guys have any ideas, opinions about this?

Thanks & regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: It did not work. The alert was not triggered. However after success do you how to call the JSON? If so please state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
function setJsonSer() {
    formData = {
        Email: 'clientlink@russell.com',
        Password: 'russell1234',
        URL: getVaria()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        complete: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/GetMessage",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        complete: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edit the 1st $.ajax({}) code snippet to display the output using the 'document.write("Set JSON Response : "+JSON.stringify(data));' . But it gave an error as the below. bold **Set JSON Response : stating that the date values are not valid**. To set the date I have used the following statement. $("#to_date").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"}); $("#from_date").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"}); I think I haven't done any mistakes. So what do you think about this matter?

Comment: Now Im getting an error as at the below. **{"readyState":4,"responseText":"soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}** What do you think about this matter?

Comment: I've seen in one blog post that this is cause by the limited no of responce charactors in the JSON. If the maxlength is increased the error will go off. So what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing data wrong.

Try

```
data: {
    'Email': 'clientlink@russell.com',
    'Password': 'russell1234',
    'URL': getVaria()
}
```

You might also want to use JSON.stringify(data) per the comment if you want to send as JSON formatted data.

EDIT

Try creating a new var - called myData - above your $.ajax command:

```
var myData = {'Email': 'clientlink@russell.com', 'Password': 'russell1234', 'URL': getVaria() };
```

The in your ajax command use this line for data:

```
data:JSON.stringify(myData);
```

Comment: Ok pal then where am I suppose to insert the JSON.stringify(data) statement? I am new to AJAX & JSON. Thanks & regards.

Comment: see new response - hth

Comment: After changing the 'data' statement according to your opinion it gave me an error " Page Cannot Be Displayed HTTP Error 405 ";

Comment: Sounds like you are now correctly sending the data (whereas before you weren't) but now you're getting an error from the API. You'll have to take a look at the API docs to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm new to Google Analytics, AJAX & JavaScript so could you exlplain what will be the reason?

Comment: Hi, sorry - I've not used that API so can't help with the API error response codes. A 405 response (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) means method not allowed - so the API is saying (probably - check the docs) that you're not allowed to do a POST method to that API endpoint.